# 動的サイトでのAmazon S3のURLの変更

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3

Rails6で作成したサイトをHerokuを使って表示しております。
画像はAmazon S3を利用しております。

サイト上の画像urlは下記になります。
`https://www.example.com/rails/active_storage/・・・・/curry.jpeg`

画像urlにアクセスすると下記のAmazon S3のurlに転送されます。
`https://example.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/variants/・・・・・`

Amazon S3のアドレスを `https://www.example.com/` から始まるurlに変更可能でしょうか？

静的サイトでは、CloudFrontとRout53を用いて変更可能なようです。

Herokuを利用した、動的サイトで変更する方法はありますでしょうか？
もしくはurlを変更するにはAmazon S3ではなく他のstorage serviceを利用することになりますか？

Comment: 該当のドメイン（`www.example.com`）で配信したいのは、S3のファイルだけですか？
それならば、S3の機能だけで可能なはずです。
それとも、Railsサーバーで動的な結果を返す部分もこのドメインで動かし、URL によって振り分けたい、という事ですか？

Comment: Railsサーバーで動的な結果を返す部分もこのドメインで動かし、URL によって振り分けたいということになります。いいねやコメントの結果を返します。

Answer (score 2):

> Amazon S3のアドレスを https://www.example.com/ から始まるurlに変更可能でしょうか？

S3だけではできません。他のサービスを前段に配置すれば、エンドポイントのURLをカスタマイズできます。CloudFrontがよく利用されます。（後述します）

> 静的サイトでは、CloudFrontとRout53を用いて変更可能なようです。
> Herokuを利用した、動的サイトで変更する方法はありますでしょうか？

Herokuの知見がないので、一般的な観点から回答します。

クラウドでWebアプリをホスティングする際、静的コンテンツと動的コンテンツで構成を分けることはよくあります。今回に当てはめると、次の構成が考えられます。

- 画像（静的コンテンツ）: CloudFront + S3
- Railsアプリ（動的コンテンツ）: Heroku

具体的には、CloudFrontに代替ドメイン名`www.example.com`を追加して、HerokuでホスティングしたRailsアプリから`https://www.example.com/...`で参照すればよいのではないでしょうか。

[CloudFront ディストリビューションでのさまざまなオリジンの使用 - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#using-s3-as-origin)

[代替ドメイン名 (CNAME) を追加することによるカスタム URL の使用 - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Herokuで関連しそうなドキュメントがありました。（Herokuでは静的コンテンツのことを「静的アセット」と呼んでいるようです）

[Amazon CloudFront CDN の使用 | Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/ja/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn)